# when does declaring a function parameter as const improve the generated code?

Tags: c++, optimization, constants

I'm asking for a discussion of the circumstances in which, in C++, declaring the parameter of a function as `const` will actually improve the *generated* code (rather than improving the source code, where appropriate `const` unambiguously adds value).

The initial motivation was code like the following lacking the `const`:

```
#include <vector>
class foo {
    public:
        foo(const std::vector<int> bar); // construct foo from vector of int
    /*...*/
    };
```

Comment: Please define "improve" (e.g., performance, readability)?

Comment: @CoryKramer: yes, I made a duplicate. Thanks for the pointer. I thus voted to close my own question (it works..)! Will delete it, I guess.

Comment: No worries, it was a great question (which is why the other has so many upvotes), I just think the duplicate has some great answers already.

Comment: This is a bad example, because what you have is just a function *declaration*, therefore the `const` gets ignored. So, no difference at all WRT not having a `const` in there.